# Kivy applications on OS X suddenly show rotated 90 degrees

Tags: macos, kivy

I've installed Kivy on my Mac (Yosemite) and it all worked fine.
I even made it to work under eclipse, so I could run kivy projects directly from it, instead of using the supplied application launcher.

Suddenly, one day, I saw that applications show on the screen, rotated by 90 degrees.
This happens to all of them, even examples I ran before and looked fine.

I don't know what caused this. Does anyone have a clue?
Is there some setting somewhere for the screen orientation, or something of that sort?

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably set the rotation parameter in kivy's config, though I don't know how. Look for kivy's config.ini (it might be in `~/.kivy/config.ini` but not sure on osx) and see if the `rotation` key under `[graphics]` is set to anything other than 0. If so...set it to 0 and try running a kivy app again.

You can also write

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'rotation', 0)
```

at the beginning of your application, *before* importing anything else.

Comment: Great! that did the trick. I also don't know how it got changed, but indeed in ~/.kivy/config.ini, the "rotation" parameter was set to 90. Thanks a lot!